# SonicWALL - 2 VPN subnets need to communicate

Tags: sonicwall

Here's my problem:

3 separate Internet locations; one of these locations is the "main" location. The other two "branch" locations connect to the main location over IPSec VPN.

What I need to do is connect the two branch locations to each other over their corresponding VPN tunnels through the main location.

Example:

Branch 1 SonicWALL (192.168.0.1) connects to Main SonicWALL (192.168.1.1) via VPN

Branch 2 SonicWALL (192.168.2.1) connects to Main SonicWALL (192.168.1.1) via VPN

Branch 1 and Branch 2 subnets need to be able to communicate with each other through their VPNs to the Main location (i.e. 192.168.2.1 <-> 192.168.1.1 <-> 192.168.0.1)

I'm aware that a VPN tunnel between the 2 Branch locations would achieve communication, but in the actual scenario this is not practical.

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this? If not, what is the best solution?

If there's anymore information needed, please let me know and I will update the question.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As KorXo mentioned, this is a standard Hub and Spoke configuration, but KorXo's link is for IPv6. Here's one for **IPv4**:

https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw3552

There's also a video. Basically you create the VPN (eg. from Branch 1 to Main) but use an **Address Object GROUP** that includes both the Main and Branch 2 subnets. That way Branch 1 understands the VPN to Main includes Main AND Branch 2's networks on the far side. The other sides are similarly configured.

An alternative is to use Tunnel (**route**) based VPNs. When you start adding additional Branch sites this makes life simpler as the VPN is just a tunnel from Branch X to Main, and ROUTES are added to allow traffic from Branch 1 to Branch X. See: https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw7902

Either would be fine in your situation (with 2 Branch sites) but one may make more sense, so have a look at both! Then choose one, try it and open a new question if you need further assistance (try to include router models, SonicOS versions, and maybe a diagram - showing interface configurations).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements is pretty much standard. It just a hub and spoke configuration.

You have a full manual with screeshots and example here https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw12024